# How to uncompress .z file using net.sf.logdistiller.util.UncompressInputStream in Java?

Tags: java, compression, inputstream, gzip

This issue is with only few files where i am ending with last line missed some characters. I am using `net.sf.logdistiller` jar. while i tried uncompressing `.gz` file it is giving full proper file.

Any help will be lauded.

Comment: is it possible to see the code?

Comment: sourceFileInputStream =new UncompressInputStream( new FileInputStream(sourceFile));

   File tempFile = null;
      tempFile = FileHelper.createFile( sourceFile.getName().substring( 0, targetFile.getName().length() - 2 ), "" );
      outputStream = new FileOutputStream( tempFile );

      // transfer bytes from the compressed file to the output file
      byte[] buf = new byte[FileHelper.COPY_BLOCK_SIZE];
      int len=0;
      while ((len = sourceFileInputStream.read(buf)) > 0)
      {
       outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
      }

Comment: I am using logdistiller-1.1.jar to uncompress .z file.

Comment: That helps, but I see nothing wrong with it. Could I please see the full code if it is possible? Sorry if I am annoying.